# cast as generic interface returns null

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface:

```
public interface IReminder<T> where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetRemindersToBeSent(IRepository<T> repository);

}
```

and class `TimesheetReminder` that implements this interface:

```
public class TimesheetReminder : IReminder<InvoiceSummary>
{

    public IEnumerable<InvoiceSummary> GetRemindersToBeSent(IRepository<InvoiceSummary> invoiceSummaryRepository)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        return invoiceSummaryRepository.List.Where(inv =>
            inv.InvoiceSummaryStatus.CKAStatusName == "Draft" &&
            inv.InsertDateUTC <= today.AddDays(-3)            &&
            inv.InsertDateUTC >= today.AddDays(-6)            &&
            inv.EndDate       <= today.AddDays(-3)
        );
    }
```

The `InvoiceSummary` implements `IIdentifyableEntity`, yet

```
public static class ReminderFactory<T> where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public static IReminder<T> GetReminder(string applicationType)
    {
        IReminder<T> reminder;

        switch (applicationType)
        {
            case "Invoicing":
                reminder = (IReminder<T>)new TimesheetReminder();
                break;
            default:
                reminder = null;
                break;
        }

        return reminder;
    }
}
```

Invoicing case returns null.

If `TimesheetReminder` didn't implement `IReminder` of an `IIdentifiableEntity` I would understand it, but it does.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's unclear where that final line of code is written and so what `T` is in scope there - but how are you sure that whatever the concrete type supplied to `T` is at that point will actually be `InvoiceSummary` rather than some *other* type that happens to be an `IIdentifiableEntity` and has no relationship to `InvoiceSummary`?

Comment: Depending on what `T` actally is you can´t cast `IRemainder<InvoiceSummary>` to `IRemainder<T>`. Quite self-explanatory, isn´t it? Maybe `T` is a sub-class  of `InvoiceSummary`? Then your interface needs to be co-variant.

Comment: Maybe what you need can be achieved by
`IReminder<InvoiceSummary> reminder = new TimesheetReminder() as IReminder<InvoiceSummary>;`
as `TimesheetReminder` specifically implements `IReminder<InvoiceSummary>` and not `IReminder<T>`

Comment: Why do you want to cast it, anyway? For example, if some methods expects a parameter of type `IReminder<T>`, then an object of type `TimesheetReminder` will be accepted.

Comment: Have amended code above to show factory, have to cast it to compile. Sure there is a way to achieve what I am trying to do but unsure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

What is `T`? `TimeSheetReminder` is `IReminder<InvoiceSummary>` so if `T` is not `InvoiceSummary` then the reference conversion is not possible:

```
class Foo: IIdentifiableEntity { ... }
var reminder = new TimesheetReminder() as IReminder<Foo>; //returns null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following....

```
IReminder<InvoiceSummary> reminder = new TimesheetReminder() as IReminder<InvoiceSummary>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating factory instance by passing ***IIdentifiableEntity*** interface as shown below:

```
var factory = ReminderFactory<IIdentifiableEntity>.GetReminder("Invoicing");
```

Which will always return **null** even when we type cast

```
reminder = new TimesheetReminder() as IReminder<T>;
```

**Solution:**

While creating factory instance, we need to pass concrete class type of ***InvoiceSummary***

```
var factory = ReminderFactory<InvoiceSummary>.GetReminder("Invoicing");
```

Even we can modify creating factory instance by removing hard coded string **"Invoicing"**

```
var factory = ReminderFactory.Create<InvoiceSummary>();
```

The sample code is shown below:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Hp --> Logic: Create factory instance by passing concrete class type.
        var factory = ReminderFactory.Create<InvoiceSummary>();
        var x = factory.GetRemindersToBeSent(new InvoiceRepository());
        x.ToList().ForEach(item =>
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.EntityName}:{item.TotalAmount}"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IIdentifiableEntity
{
    string EntityName { get; set; }
}

public static class ReminderFactory
{
    public static IReminder<T> Create<T>() where T : IIdentifiableEntity
    {
        IReminder<T> reminder = null;
        if (typeof(InvoiceSummary) == typeof(T))
        {
            reminder = new TimesheetReminder() as IReminder<T>;
        }

        return reminder;
    }
}

public interface IReminder<T> where T : IIdentifiableEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetRemindersToBeSent(IRepository<T> repository);
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
}

public class InvoiceRepository : IRepository<InvoiceSummary>
{
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceSummary> List => new List<InvoiceSummary> {
        new InvoiceSummary { EntityName = "Invoice", TotalAmount = 100.00M } };
}

public class InvoiceSummary : IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

public class TimesheetReminder : IReminder<InvoiceSummary>
{
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceSummary> GetRemindersToBeSent(
        IRepository<InvoiceSummary> repository) =>
        repository.List.Where(I => IsEqual("Invoice", I.EntityName));

    private bool IsEqual(string source, string target) =>
       string.Equals(source, target, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any other reason, if you still want to pass interface (***IIdentifiableEntity***) while creating factory instance

```
var factory = ReminderFactory<IIdentifiableEntity>.GetReminder("Invoicing");
```

**Solution (Proof of concept):** Which I don't prefer since it is bad design.

1. We need to change interfaces ***(IReminder, IRepository)*** as covaraint.
2. While reading IIdentifiableEntity data we need to cast to corresponding concreate class type.

Sample Code shown below: **Please follow code comments**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Hp --> Note: While creating factory instance we are passing interface type.
        var factory = ReminderFactory<IIdentifiableEntity>.GetReminder("Invoicing");
        var x = factory.GetRemindersToBeSent(new InvoiceRepository());

        //Hp --> Note: While reading data we need to cast to corrsponding concreate class type.
        x.Cast<InvoiceSummary>().ToList().ForEach(item =>
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.EntityName}:{item.TotalAmount}"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IRepository<out T>
{
    // Hp --> Note: You can't use setter since T it is out parameter (covariant)
    IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
}

public interface IReminder<out T> where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity
{
    //Hp --> Note: You can't use IRepository<T> here since T is out parameter (covariant)
    //Instead of T use interface IIdentifiableEntity
    IEnumerable<T> GetRemindersToBeSent(IRepository<IIdentifiableEntity> repository);
}

public class TimesheetReminder : IReminder<InvoiceSummary>
{
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceSummary> GetRemindersToBeSent(
        //Hp --> Note: We need to cast IIdentifiableEntity to corrsponding concreate class type.
        IRepository<IIdentifiableEntity> repository) =>
        repository.List.Where(I => IsEqual("Invoice", I.EntityName)).Cast<InvoiceSummary>();

    private bool IsEqual(string source, string target) =>
       string.Equals(source, target, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
}

public interface IIdentifiableEntity
{
    string EntityName { get; set; }
}

public static class ReminderFactory<T> where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public static IReminder<T> GetReminder(string applicationType)
    {
        IReminder<T> reminder;
        switch (applicationType)
        {
            case "Invoicing":
                reminder = new TimesheetReminder() as IReminder<T>;
                break;
            default:
                reminder = null;
                break;
        }
        return reminder;
    }
}

public class InvoiceRepository : IRepository<InvoiceSummary>
{
    public IEnumerable<InvoiceSummary> List => new List<InvoiceSummary> {
        new InvoiceSummary { EntityName = "Invoice", TotalAmount = 100.00M } };
}

public class InvoiceSummary : IIdentifiableEntity
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```